# What is the name of the notation $\bar{1}_x$?

Tags: vectors, notation

I do not understand what the $\bar 1_x$, $\bar 1_y$ and $\bar 1_z$ are. I'm assuming it's just a way of saying $x$, $y$ and $z$, but I'm not sure. Can someone clarify?

$$\bar r(t) = R\cos(\omega_0 t)\bar 1_x + R\sin(\omega_0 t)\bar 1_y + ct\bar 1_z$$

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics.SE! Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.  When you quote something, please give a reference with proper attribution for where you're quoting it from.

Comment: @ACuriousMind. Ill keep that in mind next time

Comment: *Im assuming its just a way of saying x,y and z* If that were so, the right side would not be a vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\bar 1_x$, $\bar 1_y$ and $\bar 1_z$ are [unit vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_vector) parallel to the $x$, $y$ and $z$ axes respectively. This is a slightly unusual notation - it is more common to see these unit vectors written as $\hat x$, $\hat y$, $\hat z$ or  $\hat e_x$, $\hat e_y$, $\hat e_z$.